# Telerik:How To Convert Docx File To PDF

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik, persian

We are developing a silverlight project  .this project contains  many services  and lots of controls. we used a [Telerik RadrichTextBox version](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#RichTextBox/TelerikEditor) (2012.3.1017.1050) to working with  Docx file in Persian language . and we need to convert it to PDF OR TIF inside Project on the fly . If you go to telerik demo and take a look those demos, you find out this control has a ability to convert DOCX to PDF or TIF, but it does not work for Persian alphabet. your guide  improve our accuracy and help us to learn collaborate behavior.
Thanks for your favor...

Update :
This our File is something like this :
[image]
after converting to PDf we get this result:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What you see in PDF output? Random characters? Incorrect direction or alignment? Can you attach a picture?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should upgrade the telerik to 2016 Q1.
2. You should config the localization of your report to `fa`. You can refer to [Localizing Reports](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/advanced-localizing-reports) for more information.